# Concatenate columns containing lists by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a logically simple problem but am going round in circles at the moment and could really appreciate some help.

I have ONE DataFrame which has as an index "datetime" objects. Furthermore, I have one column called "data" that contains one list of floats:

```
                 data
    timestamp
    27.04.2020   [1.1,  2.2]   
    27.04.2020   [3.3,  4.4]
    27.04.2020   [5.5,  6.6]
    26.04.2020   [7.7,  8.8]
    26.04.2020   [9.9,  10.10]
```

I now want everything to be merged by timestamp. So the 1st to 3rd row should be merged into a single list and so on:

```
                 data
    timestamp
    27.04.2020   [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6]   
    26.04.2020   [7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.10]
```

This is a minimal sample, I have 3 or more equal timestamps that need to be merged.

I have looked through many different topics that have been opened but couldn't find one that deals with one single DataFrame and lists.

Every help is appcriated,

Rising

Comment: `df.groupby('timestamp').sum()`?

Comment: Perhaps `df.groupby(level=0).sum()` @quang

Comment: @yatu if index has a name, either way would work.

Comment: U right, it should work too being a named index @quang

Comment: It works with sum... but how and why? How does pandas know that the two lists should not be summed item by item but rather merged?

Comment: It's not pandas. In python you can sum lists to *concatenate* them: try `[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]`

Comment: ah okay, thanks you very much :)